# Not able to get the actual content of web page in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web, web-scraping, web-crawler

The URL: [URL whose data I Want](https://www.google.co.in/search?espv=2&q=Adidas%20Delhi&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=28561566,77158033,3898&tbm=lcl&ved=0ahUKEwi7pPeGhuPNAhUHN48KHSyTCAgQjGoIRg) when traced through Python 2.7 using following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import requests  
import urlparse  
import re
import urllib  
import urllib2  
URL=[URL whose data I Want][1]  
page = requests.get(URL)  
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")  
fo = open("new.html", "wb")  
fo.write(str(soup))  
fo.close()
```

Gives output like [observed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ioF0.jpg) While it was expected to give output that I see on browser (URL mentioned earlier).
1. How to get the expected data?
2. Can some one figure out why is it so, because URL is same but its not getting the same data?  Thanks

Comment: You could try using the Google Maps API

Comment: The map and table are probably not in the initial HTML of the page. Try selenium to simulate a browser session and get the content you want.

Comment: Don't know but for some reason selenium is giving error:

from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe')

 Error comes like:
WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0

Comment: Selenium worked for me.. Thank you

Comment: @BSingh Can't use normal chrome with Selenium. You'll have to use chromedriver